# Routing in webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I am playing around with [Google Course Builder](https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/).
It's built using Google App Engine and the webapp2 framework.

I am not very familiar with webapp2 and routing in general and I think that's the reason for my doubt. And perhaps the people who have previously worked on GCB would be able to answer this question.

I am editing a view (as in MVC). It's an HTML file. I created a hyperlink to an another view (which is an HTML file I created myself), but I am getting a 404 when I click on the link.

I tried out all possible variations to the file location.

```
href="views/doubts.html"
```

would open "localhost:8080/views/doubts.html". But it gives me a 404 even thought he file exists.
I tried out all variations ("/views/doubts", just "doubts.html", "doubts" and so on).

Perhaps direct access to the views might be blocked by some other part of the application. In such a case, what is the preferred way to go about it? Do I have to create a controller which redirects or so? I have never used MVC before.

Comment: Are you using a template engine?  How are you rendering the initial html file? I'm going to answer the question assuming that you are using a template engine of some sort to render html files.  Edit:  I can't answer this without some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `app.yaml` first. The `app.yaml` decide how gogole app engine response for each kind of request. 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

Basically there are two ways google app engine used to response the request.

1. response via static files
   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers

> Static files are files to be served directly to the user for a given
>   URL, such as images, CSS stylesheets, or JavaScript source files.
>   Static file handlers describe which files in the application directory
>   are static files, and which URLs serve them.

2 . response via script
   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Script_Handlers

> A script handler executes a Python script to handle the request that
>   matches the URL pattern. The mapping defines a URL pattern to match,
>   and the script to be executed. In Python 2.5, CGI is the preferred
>   method of defining script handlers. In Python 2.7, WSGI is the
>   preferred method. CGI works in Python 2.7, but some features of the
>   runtime, such as concurrent requests, are available only if your app
>   uses WSGI.

The 1) method allow user to host a simple static website without touch the `webapp2` or `url routing`

Comment: Thanks. I went for the second option and assigned a handler to the request.